# Можно ли рассчитывать коллизию у метода pygame.draw?

Tags: python, pygame

Мне надо рассчитывать столкновение двух объектов это можно сделать если объекты вызваны через класс с помощью collision но с помощью pygame.draw объект не имеет такого атрибута как быть?